# Is there a way to delete bone constraints by name?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, constraints

I'm trying to delete all bone constraints containing part of the name 'Action' for selected pose bones. I'm still learning scripting and this is the best I could come up with. Any pointers would be really appreciated!

```
import bpy    

for bone in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    if 'Action' in pose.bones.constraints.name:
        bpy.ops.pose.constraints_clear()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the constraints with name "Action" **or** delete the constraints from bone which contain "Action" in bone's name? I will assume the later one in my following answer:

---

- Use `bone.constraints.remove(constraint)` instead of operator. [armature - delete bone constraint in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40244/delete-bone-constraint-in-python)
- Directly use what you get from for loop

```
import bpy

for bone in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    if 'Action' in bone.name:
        # Iterate over all the bone's constraints and delete them all
        for c in bone.constraints:
            bone.constraints.remove(c)  # Remove constraint
```

---

```
import bpy

for bone in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    for c in bone.constraints:
        if 'Action' in c.name:
            bone.constraints.remove(c)  # Remove constraint
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't think I explained that well. It's for Constraints on all bones with 'Action' in the constraints name. This deletes all constraints for bones with 'Action' in the bone name.

Comment: @adam like this? Sorry I don't know constraint can be named with 'Action'

Comment: just copied the data path
pose.bones["Action"].constraints["Action move up"].name

Comment: Brilliant, second one works great thanks for your help!

Comment: @adam if this has answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green tick beside answer.